# Linguagem que os software da Autodesk utilizam

Tags: c, c++

Estou querendo saber em qual linguagem os Softwares da `Autodesk` são escritos e qual o nome da GUI utilizada. Se puderem me ajudar com essas informações.

Comment: Boa noite Wesley, acredito que o codigo fonte do software seja proprietario e portanto somente os desenvolvedores poderiam informar isto. As GUIs provavelmente são proprietárias também e portanto não e algo opensource que você pode usar "a vontade". Existe o QT que usa QSS pra estilizar as janelas e elementos, usa C++ e pode ser compilado em Windows, Linux e Mac. Com ele vc pode atingir o efeito desejado das GUIs. Veja https://www.qt.io

Answer (score 2):

Boa noite Wesley,

Infelizmente essa é uma informação que você não irá conseguir com precisão, mas não se preocupe porque não faria muita diferença saber isso.

Os grandes softwares como o Autocad são escrito em uma misto de linguagens, como C, C++ e Assembly, e a depender da plataforma pode envolver linguagens diferentes.

Um abraço.

Comment: Prove o que você está falando.

Comment: Provar o que, amigo? Não entendi... Abs

Comment: O que você está falando. Não vasta você dizer que é isto. Prove que isto é verdade. Eu estou questionando esta informação. Dê uma referência que mostre que isto é verdade.

Comment: Bom, o que comprova minha resposta é justamente a ausência de uma fonte. Você não encontrará uma página dizendo "não vamos contar que linguagem utilizamos".

Um abraço.

Comment: Nem que foi contada, então você está só chutando isto. Você tem que provar o que você fala. Pelo menos as pessoas agora sabem que esta "resposta" não tem relevância alguma, é só um comentário do que você **acha** que é.

Answer (score 1):

O Maya do AutoDesk foi feito usando o QT com C++, QT é muito avançado e fácil de se aprender.